# Add mime type based on name rather than extension

Tags: apache, apache2, plone, mime-types, apache2.4

I wonder whether it is possible to let Apache 2.4 efficiently add a mime type to a file *without* using a file extension.

My use case is a Plone server which is served in an Apache virtual host.
This Plone application has a search index which contains a metadata value `getThumbnailPath`; when displaying search results, I'd use this value directly.

Sometimes that thumbnail is calculated from the object (if it contains image information; usually yielding a `JPG` image), and sometimes (and as a fallback), it is simply based on its type (usually a `PNG`-type pictogram).  This calculation is not done during search result display but *before*, when the object is modified and the catalog metadata is updated.

Now I'd like to have those thumbnails *in two or more sizes* (all in 4:3 width-to-height ratio):

- One size for pretty overview pages (which I already have; `240x180`)
- One smaller size for general search results (`120x90`; the only size I'd need for *every* searchable object in my site)
- One or two slightly larger sizes for use in carousels (only needed for the newest N objects of each type)

Of course, there shouldn't be any difference between those thumbnails (apart from the size); the idea is to be able to choose between those sizes by simply adding a suffix like `-120`, `-240` and the like.
I'd like to avoid the need for more than one `getThumbnailPath` metadata value per object.

I'd like as well to do as few calculations as possible during display. Of course it would be ok to simply append `-120` to each `<img src>` during search result display and use `-240` in the "pretty overview pages", but I'd consider it too much calculation effort to split the filename and inject the size information for each found topic. My display templates should be as simple as possible.

So, what are my options?

- I could use some name-based filter (if supported by Apache); currently all files which match `picto-.*` in a certain location share the `image/png` type
- I could have apache decide about the type based on the file content. (the slowest solution, right?)
- I could define a few additional extensions for Apache to recognize, e.g. `AddType image/png .png-120 .png-240` and `AddType image/jpeg .jpg-120 .jpg-240`
- I could let Apache serve `application/octed-stream` (as it currently does) and have the user agent detect the image type.

Which is the solution you'd prefer, and which would perform best?

(Apache 2.4, CentOS 7)

Comment: a) rewrite the path, Plone templates make this easy enough b) use mod_rewrite to rewrite incoming URLs that end in known sizes (perhaps with a `RewriteMap`), from `.png-<size>` to `-<size>.png` when serving.

Comment: Splitting strings is not much effort, not compared to all the other work that Plone templates already do, anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You are right, they do a lot of work. But I'd like to bring this down to a minimum; and the best thing you can do with catalog metadata is: use it as it is.
The RewriteRule is (or ...Map; didn't use this for now) is an idea missing in my list. Of course I have quite some already. Perhaps it is preferable to avoid rewriting when there are other solutions as well (hoping for feedback from Apache experts).